# BigBlueButton installation on webserver

Tags: ubuntu, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to install (http://bigbluebutton.org/) on a webserver, for my company in order to use the tool.
the problem is that i can't find any commandline on the Cpanel of the server.
I'm really lost and cant find a way on how to install this.
i have a windows 7 computer, and i don't know anything about ubuntu

I have tied to install on localhost, but i don't know how at all because i have no ubuntu and just windows7 and xampp

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I understand you wants to install BBB on windows7 box , as per my knowledge BBB do not supports windows box.

However, if you wants to use the same windows7 box , you can install docker for windows (http://docs.docker.com/windows/started/) 
on your windows machine and pull ubuntu image and can install BBB.

Hope this helps